# Snap programs show only files inside /home

Tags: filesystem, snap

Is there a way to open files stored outside `/home` directory?

For example, I've got a shared disk formatted in ZFS that auto mounts stuff in `/Volumes/dataset_name` I use it to transfer big projects from and to my Mac. OK, that's a weird case, but can't access anything mounted in `/media` either and well, now that's kinda...

Also, have to point that isn't about one particular snapped program, I've installed many recommended on OMG Ubuntu to test them and so far none had the ability to open anything outside `/home`; last case but **by no means the only one** KeePassXC.

Have tried using symlinks and changing some directories permissions but to no avail.

Comment: You'd need to 1st. remove the snap then install it again using either the `--classic` or `--devmode` option. Try `--classic` first...

Comment: With `--classic` I could open things on `/media` but `/Volumes` is still not being listed. Same when using `--devmode`. If I run `sudo mkdir /asdasd` The program doesn't show this directory either.

Comment: Yeah, what you see may be as good as it gets atm with snaps which are still a bit of a joke. So most newly (user) created directories in / aren't accessible. Ex. - /tmp, /usr/share/, pretty much all of /usr/local, ect. What's weird though  is a new folder/file in /etc can be..

Comment: Please don't recommend installing things with `--classic` or `--devmode` unless the upstream developer intended it. Those have implications for users. We're seeing users are following this advice and breaking their snap installs. Installing with devmode will disable automatic updates, and break confinement. Installing with classic mode will bypass confinement and may break the application completely as library paths are all wrong.